# How to calculate BMI (Body Mass Index) from CSV file data in java?

Tags: java, csv

How do I calculate *Body Mass Index* (BMI) using data from a csv file in java?  I have already read the details from the file - now I want to calculate the BMI value using the data:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

public class Hct216Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String student="input.csv" ; 
        File input=new File(student);    
        try {
            Scanner inputStream=new Scanner(input);
            while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data=inputStream.next();
                String[] values =data.split(",");
                System.out.println(values[0] + " -  " + values[1] + " - " + values[2]);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added some grammatical improvements and formatted your code to look better. This *may* attract more answers.

Comment: What are you having a problem with, exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. BMI is a simple calculation (once you have numbers and not strings)--what specifically is causing a problem? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your CSV is written but you told us that you read it so the only thing you have to do now is to use the formula : bmi=kg/m² where kg is the person's weight in kilograms and m² the person's height in meter. I'm not sure if that was the problem because the formula can be easely found on the internet.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

New programmers tend to worry too much about input and output.  I'd recommend focusing on the function itself:

```
/**
 * @link https://www.cdc.gov/nccdphp/dnpao/growthcharts/training/bmiage/page5_2.html
 */
public class BMICalculator {

    public static final double CONVERSION_POUNDS_AND_INCHES = 703.0;

    private final double conversion;

    public BMICalculator() { this(CONVERSION_POUNDS_AND_INCHES); }

    public BMICalculator(double conversion) { 
        this.conversion = conversion;
    }

    public double calculateIndex(double weight, double height) {
        return this.conversion*weight/height/height;
    }
}
```

Learn [JUnit](https://junit.org) and write good unit tests.  Prove that your function works, then move on to input and output.

What about negative weights and heights?  What should your function do if these are entered?  What about zero height?  What will your function do?  Write tests for each one.

You're a new developer.  One thing you might consider is the new JDK 8 functional interfaces.  You can use lambdas that way:

```
public class BMICalculator implements ToDoubleBiFunction<Double, Double>{

    public static final double CONVERSION = 703.0;

    public double applyAsDouble(Double weightPounds, Double heightInches) {
        return CONVERSION*weightPounds/heightInches/heightInches;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's the route you're going re: function interface, wouldn't it be better to make `BMICalculator` an interface which extends `ToDoubleBiFunction`?

Comment: Why?  Seems clear enough.  Interfaces make sense if there will be multiple implementations.  I don't see a need.  I added the functional interface so he could use it in lambdas.  Might be helpful if there's a .csv to read from.  The only change I might consider is adding a constructor that takes in a conversion and allows different input units.

Comment: I suppose I'm thinking ahead in terms of inheritance: what if someone wanted to inherit the method from `BMICalculator` without sacrificing what they currently are (e.g. extending some abstract class which isn't modifiable, or if they're using an enum). I realize it's a little silly in this situation, but I can't explicitly rule it out in my mind. Functional interfaces seem backwards here anyhow; you use them to allow the programmer to supply the behavior you need, not to specify it outright. Java is able to resolve `BMICalculator::calculateIndex` as a BiFunction without the interface

Comment: I gave two implementations and a reason for each one.  YAGNI would tell me I shouldn't worry about inheritance.

Comment: Keeping with YAGNI, aren't you adding more than you need? You can do `ToDoubleBiFunction<Double, Double> dubs = BMICalculator::calculateIndex` without implementing any interface at all. I'm just not seeing the purpose, so I suppose I'm mending my original point from "using an interface" to "why bother with implementing TDBiF at all".

Comment: Like I said, I did the simple thing as a proposal to the student.  The addition of the interface is to make them aware of the functional interfaces.  Not presented as a "must do".  This is for education.  Feel free to propose your own answer if you don't like mine.

Comment: Okay, understandable enough for me. I'm just prodding the morning curiosity in case I was missing something myself; not trying to attack your answer